# On running spring boot war from cmd getting error resolving template exception in thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

On running the spring boot war file from the command line why I am getting the below error in thymeleaf :
Error resolving template, template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers.
I have changed the default thymeleaf template folder location using spring.thymeleaf.prefix property in application properties file. However, when I run the same code using IDEs it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

Oh ok I got the issue, it was with the html file name which i was returning from my controller. I was using / with the file name (e.g. /index) because of which it was failing. But i am amazed that the IDEs are smart enough to detect that issue and somehow internally auto corrected it while running. That's why it was running via IDEs but failing while running the war from command line.